# Want to sum of values with same property name in object using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

Hi I want to do sum of the quantity for each reason name.And I have 2 arrays as per below.

```
var allreasonsids=[];
 allreasonsids = [
   {reasonid: 1, reasonname: abc}, 
   {reasonid: 2, reasonname: def}, 
   {reasonid: 3, reasonname: ghi}, 
   {reasonid: 4, reasonname: jkl}
];


var reasonsandcount=[];
reasonsandcount=[
{reasonid: 1, quantity: 5},
{reasonid: 2, quantity: 10},
{reasonid: 1, quantity: 3},
{reasonid: 3, quantity: 4},
{reasonid: 1, quantity: 2},
{reasonid: 2, quantity: 6}
];
```

I want the result as per below:

**Output:**
abc :10

def:16

ghi:4

jkl:0

Please suggest me any answer.
Thank You.

Comment: use basic javascipt or https://linqjs.codeplex.com/

Comment: @lordkain Hi I am using basic javascript. can u please tell me solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `Array.prototype.reduce`, `Object.keys` and `Array.prototype.forEach` functions:

```js
var allreasonsids = [{reasonid: 1, reasonname: 'abc'}, {reasonid: 2, reasonname: 'def'}, {reasonid: 3, reasonname: 'ghi'}, {reasonid: 4, reasonname: 'jkl'}],
    reasonsandcount = [{reasonid: 1, quantity: 5},{reasonid: 2, quantity: 10},{reasonid: 1, quantity: 3},{reasonid: 3, quantity: 4},{reasonid: 1, quantity: 2},{reasonid: 2, quantity: 6}];

// getting sums for grouped `reasonid` items
var sums = reasonsandcount.reduce(function (a, b) {
  (a[b.reasonid]) ? a[b.reasonid] += b.quantity : a[b.reasonid] = b.quantity;
  return a;
}, {});

var result = {}, keys = Object.keys(sums);
allreasonsids.forEach(function (o) {
    this[o.reasonname] = (keys.indexOf(o.reasonid + "") !== -1)? sums[o.reasonid] : 0;
}, result);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for help.But in actual I have reason name with space e.g.New Stock instead of abc.so I cannot access the value in result object with result.New Stock .Can you please help me.

Comment: Hi RomanPerekhrest, sums  variable is so helpful to me.With some little extra effort I am able to get what I want.Thanx again.

Comment: @chhaya_patel, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

You can use `reduce()` and `filter()` to return object as result.

```js
var allreasonsids = [
  {reasonid: 1, reasonname: 'abc'}, 
  {reasonid: 2, reasonname: 'def'}, 
  {reasonid: 3, reasonname: 'ghi'}, 
  {reasonid: 4, reasonname: 'jkl'}
];

var reasonsandcount=[
  {reasonid: 1, quantity: 5},
  {reasonid: 2, quantity: 10},
  {reasonid: 1, quantity: 3},
  {reasonid: 3, quantity: 4},
  {reasonid: 1, quantity: 2},
  {reasonid: 2, quantity: 6}
];

var result = allreasonsids.reduce(function(r, e) {
  var quant = reasonsandcount.filter(function(a) {
    return e.reasonid == a.reasonid
  }).reduce(function(re, el) {
    return re + el.quantity
  }, 0)
  r[e.reasonname] = quant;
  return r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

You can also just use `reduce()` and `forEach()` loop.

```js
var allreasonsids = [
  {reasonid: 1, reasonname: 'abc'}, 
  {reasonid: 2, reasonname: 'def'}, 
  {reasonid: 3, reasonname: 'ghi'}, 
  {reasonid: 4, reasonname: 'jkl'}
];

var reasonsandcount=[
  {reasonid: 1, quantity: 5},
  {reasonid: 2, quantity: 10},
  {reasonid: 1, quantity: 3},
  {reasonid: 3, quantity: 4},
  {reasonid: 1, quantity: 2},
  {reasonid: 2, quantity: 6}
];

var result = allreasonsids.reduce(function(r, e) {
 var quant = 0;
 reasonsandcount.forEach(el => el.reasonid == e.reasonid ? quant+=el.quantity : 0);
 r[e.reasonname] = quant;
 return r
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: thanx a lot for helping me.But in actual I have reason name with space e.g.New Stock.so I cannot access the value in result object with result.New Stock .Can you please help me out?If any confusion in this then please ask me

Comment: ,If the result is in any list or array then also it is good for me.if that will be possible then can you give me result in that?

Comment: I get What I want thanx for your time.